# Write cronjob output into a different named file on each run

Tags: php, cron

I am running a php script though a cronjob using the following :

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q  /home/hduser/Documents/WebCrawl-ProtestData/preg_match.php > /home/hduser/Documents/cronoutput.txt

the script executes every minute and stroes the output in :

```
/home/hduser/Documents/cronoutput.txt
```

is there a way of storing the output in a new file on every run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put variables into your crontab file and use them in your command:

```
 DATE_STRING =date +%s

 */1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /home/hduser/Documents/WebCrawl-ProtestData/preg_match.php > /home/hduser/Documents/cronoutput_$($DATE_STRING).txt
```

In this case I create a string of the date command and evaluate in the filename (adding an epoch timestamp to the file name)

Note that the initial assignment does not evaluate, as cron is not a shell, but the command line that cron execute does evaluate the string `date +%s` when used in the output file name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is simple and can be done a number of ways. The sanest is to create a bash script that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

datestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)
outfile=cronoutput-${datestamp}.txt

/usr/bin/php -q /home/hduser/Documents/WebCrawl-ProtestData/preg_match.php > \
/home/hduser/Documents/$outfile
```

Store it in say runwebcrawl.sh  Make runwebcrawl.sh executable

```
chmod 0755 runwebcrawl.sh
```

The call runwebcrawl.sh from your crontab

```
*/1 * * * * runwebcrawl.sh
```

It will create files named:

```
cronoutput-20140618-123456.txt
```